# Partial derivatives of a "quadratic form"

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let
$$
Q(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2 + 2\sum_{1\leqq i < j\leqq n}a_{ij}x_ix_j
$$
be defined on $ \mathbb R^n $, where the $ a_{ij} $ are a bunch of real scalars.

I need to compute the partial derivative
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_\lambda}\Biggr|_{(q_0,\dots,q_n)}
$$
at a point $ (q_0,\dots,q_n)\in \mathbb R^n $, for $ \lambda = 1,\dots,n $.

My calculation gives the following result
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_\lambda}\Biggr|_{(q_0,\dots,q_n)} = 2\biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{\lambda - 1} a_{i\lambda}q_i + a_{\lambda\lambda} q_\lambda + \sum_{j = \lambda + 1}^n a_{\lambda j}q_j\biggr)
$$
which should be correct (modulo some typos).

The book I'm reading reports that
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x_\lambda}\Biggr|_{(q_0,\dots,q_n)} = 2\sum_{j = 1}^n a_{\lambda j}q_j
$$
as if $ a_{ij} = a_{ji} $. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Isn't there some one-to-one correspondence between quadratic forms and symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadratic forms are usually given by matrices, so $Q(x) = x^TAx $ where $x$ is the column vector $(x_1, x_2, ... ,x_n)$ and A has entries $a_{ij}$. If you multiply this out you will see that it gives the same Q as in your question.

Any matrix can be written as $A = \frac{A^T + A}{2} + \frac{A^T - A}{2}$ where the first term is symmetric and the second is antisymmetric. Since $x^TAx = x^T( \frac{A^T+ A}{2} + \frac{A^T- A}{2})x = x^T\frac{A^T+ A}{2}x + x^T\frac{A^T- A}{2}x$ and also $(x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx$ it must be that $x^T\frac{A^T- A}{2}x = 0$ for all x, so the antisymmetric part doesn't affect the quadratic form.

So you can assume A is symmetric. That is also why they've written it as a sum over i < j and multiplied it by 2, because $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. I think you may have overlooked that they are not summing over all i and j. The sum has $\frac{{n \choose 2}}{2}$ terms and not $n^2$.

In general it's useful to remember that the gradient of $x^TAx$ is $(A^T + A)x$ and that since $x^TAx = x^T(\frac{A^T+ A}{2})x$, if we already have a symmetric matrix, $A = \frac{A^T+ A}{2}$ so the gradient is $2Ax$.